# Adding a RadioButton to a WPF ListItem in XAML using a ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, radio-button, controltemplate

Following [gehho's answer to "MVVM Group Radio Button"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2713623/575530) I'm trying to add a radio button to a list item such that when the list item is selected the radio button gets checked, and when the list item is not selected the radio button is unchecked. Kelly has [a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1427790/575530) to his or her "Binding RadioButton IsChecked to ListBoxItem IsSelected and ListBox IsFocused" question that looks like it should do what I need. However my simple transposition of Kelly's XAML is not working - the radio buttons remain unchecked. Here is the entirety of my MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:SampleData="clr-namespace:Expression.Blend.SampleData.SampleDataSource" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="RadioButton.MainWindow"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="640" Height="480">

    <Window.Resources>
        <SampleData:SampleDataSource x:Key="SampleDataSource" d:IsDataSource="True"/>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="LBItemControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Property1}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <RadioButton x:Name="rbIsSelected" IsChecked="False" IsEnabled="False"/>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                        <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" TargetName="rbIsSelected" Value="True"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ListBoxItemTemplate">
            <ListBoxItem Template="{StaticResource LBItemControlTemplate}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource SampleDataSource}}">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemTemplate}" SelectionMode="Single"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Can anyone see why this is not working and suggest a fix or a different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know that `ItemsControls` will automatically create a Container item for every data item found? Your `DataTemplate` contains a `ListBoxItem` which is never correct. You basically say "When you display my content in a ListBoxItem, create a new ListBoxItem". So your code relys on your detached `ListBoxItem`, which can never be selected, because its not a container item in an `ItemsControl`, therefore it can't work. Your `DataTemplate` is only the content inside the Container, in this case the DataTemplate should define how your data should look in a `ListBoxItem`.

This is a small but not necessarly good practice example, but it shows that you don't have to create a `ListBoxItem`, it is automatically there:

Somewhere as a resource, Window.Resources or app.xaml for example:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

And the usage itself

```
<ListBox x:Name="test" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate}"/>
```

The listbox in this case would need to get an ItemsSource set in the code behind.

Comment: Perfect - it was the `RelativeSource`/`FindAncestor`/`AncestorType` stuff I was completely forgetting. This is just what I want and works as needed with `RadioButton` instead of `Checkbox`. Thanks for the gentle informative explanation too.